# How to import a route in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

It is necessary to transfer the routes to a separate file in the Flask project.
But it doesn’t work out.
I made a simple example for clarity:

app.py

```py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask (__name__)
import route
if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run ()
```

route.py

```py
from app import app
@app.route ('/')
def hello_world ():
     return 'Hello World!'
```

Everything starts fine:
`app.py`
but when entering the page:
`127.0.0.1∗5000`
it writes:
Not found

And it seems like the task is simple, but I just can’t solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... I'm by no means an expert but I generally use the following structure.

```
main.py
subfolder    
  __init__.py
  route.py
```

```py
# main.py
from subfolder import app
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)

# __init__.py
from flask import Flask
    app = Flask (__name__)
    from subfolder import route

# route.py
from subfolder import app

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'
```

This way app is simply available in the folder where it's created by init. That is, inside the subfolder. Then it's straightforward to import it.